# How to add reminder for the app React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have an app and I want to set a reminder to open the app it is the same native reminder.
eg: when user set reminder is 7:00 AM and every day my app will alarm.

My idea is to create a notification and the app will be opened by another library when listening to the notif. I want my app will auto-open when the lock screen opens. Maybe It is only possible on android. I need some solutions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) will help you. visit the "Scheduled Notifications" part. after the scheduled time when the notification appears on the screen, user can open the app  by pressing the notification

Comment: The problem is I want to open the app without press the notification for Android. It works fine on android and I have seen this app. it is quite difficult. Press the notif I'll use it for ios. But android I want to auto-open the app when the notif becoming. :(. Do you have idea for it.?

Comment: But I am not sure this app using React Native. But I think it must work for Android.

Comment: on android i think you can use alarm manager that open your application on specific time

Answer (score 0):

So, Any one looking for the solution for both the platform to invoke native notification here is the library that does most of the work behind the scenes.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-events